# RequestPermissions not showing a dialog box

Tags: android, android-manifest, runtime-permissions

I found a lot of similar topics with the same threat but I still can't find a solution for my problem. I wrote this code to grant the writing permission to the app but there is no dialog box showing. I get in the monitor the No writing permission messages.

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
Log.i("permissions", "No writing permission");

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
```

I added the permission in the AndroidManifest fils

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Changed the target `sdk targetSdkVersion 23`, and I am using `android 6.0.1`.

**Edit:**
I also tied this code but it still not working

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
```

Comment: what version of the device are you using ?

Comment: I just copied your code and it works properly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequestPermissions Dialog will not be shown only in below 2 cases on device **>= 6.0:**

1) Either you have already given permission to the any of the Dangerous Permissions within the Category you are asking for.

2) You had clicked **Never Ask Again** checkbox when the dialog had shown previously.

Comment: Got the link for point 1.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#rmp

Comment: @Ashish Shukla suppose clicked clicked Never Ask Again option after next time how to show request permission dialog?

Comment: @krishna Use this link : https://medium.com/@begalesagar/method-to-detect-if-user-has-selected-dont-ask-again-while-requesting-for-permission-921b95ded536

Answer (score 3):

I had a similiar case. Do not try to call it with `ActivityCompat` from a Fragment. Instead use the given `requestPermissions` method from the Fragment e.g.

```
 requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
```